# displaying a list of lists in django template

Tags: javascript, html, django

> i have the following list of lists : [[ "task1","task2"],["task3","task4", "task5"]]
>   and I'm trying to display each list on the x axis of a graph ( so in total I have 2 graphs) in the HTML template using a script as follow:

```
{% for j in range %}


<script>

        var x = "id"+{{j}};
        var myChart = document.getElementById(x).getContext('2d');
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Arial';
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'Darkblue';


        var massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type: 'line', //bar horizontalbar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
            data:{
                labels:[

                    {% for t in tas %}
                    {% for s in t %}

                    '{{s}}',

                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                        ],
                datasets:[{
                    label: 'Points',
                    data:[{% for foo in pend %} '{{foo.pending_task.points_upon_completion}}' ,{% endfor %} ],
                    backgroundColor:"grey",

                    borderWidth:2,
                    borderColor:'black'
                }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display: true,
                    text:"Productivity",
                    fontSize:20
                },
                legend:{
                    display: false // show or not show
                    //position:'', // change position maybe left right

                },
                layout:{
                    padding:{
                        left:0,
                        right:0,
                        top:0,
                        botton:0
                    },
                }
            }
        });

    </script>

   {% endfor %}
```

> but it's not working, I'm not able to separate the two lists

Comment: It will help you if converted to one dimension array?

Comment: no i dont think that it will help. how can I convert it anyway. and if converted how can I display each list alone on the x axis